# Why when starting the timer in the new class it's working but when trying to stop the timer it's not?

Tags: java, android-studio

For some reason the timer start fine but never stop.

I created a new class:

```
package com.test.webservertest;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by me on 11/18/2015.
 */

public class Timers
{
    private long startTime = 0L;
    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
    private long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    private long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    private long updatedTime = 0L;
    private String recordtimer;
    private Runnable updateTimerThread;

    public void StartTimer(TextView timerValue) {
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread = new UpdateTimerThread(timerValue), 0);
    }

    public void StopTimer(TextView timerValue) {
        timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
        customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread = new UpdateTimerThread(timerValue));
    }


    public class UpdateTimerThread implements Runnable {
        protected TextView timerValue;

        public UpdateTimerThread(TextView timerValue) {
            this.timerValue= timerValue;
        }

        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (timeInMilliseconds / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int hours = mins / 60;
            mins = mins % 60;
            recordtimer = "Recording Time: " + String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" + String.format("%02d", mins) + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs);
            timerValue.post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    timerValue.setText(recordtimer);
                }
            });
            //set yout textview to the String timer here
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }


}
```

Then in MainActivity i did:

```
if (is_start == true)
                                {
                                    timers.StartTimer(timerValueRecord);  
                                    response = Get(iptouse + "start");
                                    is_start = false;
                                } else
                                {
                                    timers.StopTimer(timerValueRecord);
                                    textforthespeacch = "Recording stopped and preparing the file to be shared on youtube";
                                    MainActivity.this.initTTS();
                                    response = Get(iptouse + "stop");
                                    is_start = true;
                                    startuploadstatusthread = true;
                                    servercheckCounter = 0;
                                }
```

The timer then start but it's not stopping when it's doing the

```
timers.StopTimer(timerValueRecord);
```

I checked with a breakpoint it's getting there but the timer never stop and continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
```

and not

```
customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread = new UpdateTimerThread(timerValue));
```

You can't expect the handler to find an Object if you destroy it to make a new one in its place.